# Uncaught exception 'Dailymotion API Exception' with message 'This video format is not supported

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am getting this error when video uploading in daily motion using API, but two days ago I did get any error, successfully updated

Error

Uncaught exception 'DailymotionApiException' with message 'This video format is not supported'

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, this means that the format of the video file you provide is not valid or not supported. Can you check the following:

- that the video source is valid
- that the video file respects the following specifications: https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/203790706-Upload-specifications-and-encoding-settings Maybe your video file is too long or too big?